# How to create menu for environment variable names and values starting with $zv?

Tags: command-line, bash, autocomplete

Wow! I've been browsing similar questions for 2h+ here! I'm sure I just want a quite simple thing.

In a bash session with many functions we have dozens of directories to visit. Their names are all held in variables beginning with `$zv`. We use variables because the real names are very long.

Some are simple and memorable, like `$zvv`. But there's also things like `$zvdirection` that can appear. And the crucial thing that the list of available variables changes. The user is never sure what `$zv...` vars will be available. Some will be entirely new, auto-generated.

So she will usually do this:

```
cd $zv <tab> <tab>
```

No hard work there. She gets a list, and manually completes her `cd $zv` line. But these users need to use these dirs fast, all the time, often with novel `$zv...` variables being generated by hidden scripts.

So. What I've been trying for 2+ hours for is a function, say `zv`, which will show them all the currently available `$zv...` autocompletes, and then hopefully also give them at a `cd $zv` prompt, where bash is waiting for them to add the remaining characters.

I'm so sure this function must be a one liner, but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
arr=()
while read v; do arr+=( "$(printf "%s=%s" "$v" "${!v}")" ); done < <(compgen -v zv)
select i in "${arr[@]}"; do cd "${i#*=}"; break; done
```

This uses bashs `select` builtin to provide simple menu-based dialogs.

---

- `arr=()` initializes the array
- `while ...` reads the input and fills the array.

  - `arr+=( "..." )` adds new entries to the array.
  - `printf "%s=%s" "$v" "${!v}"` ...prints the variable name and its contents.
- `compgen -v zv` generates the list of all variables that would be completed when typing `$zv<tab><tab>`.
- This list is given to `select` to generate the menu.

  - `cd "${i#*=}"` this `cd`s into the directory given in the variable after the first occuring `=`.

Comment: Thank you! The "compgen -v zv" part is exactly what i was hoping for, and the select menu is an excellent extra. I will use it. Your answer goes above and beyond the call of duty, well done.